# Mapping one vector to different pairs even though the vector is different by the time it maps to each pair?

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble mapping vectors to integer pairs. My question comes down to, If a have only one vector that am clearing at the beginning of a for loop, filling and then assigning to a pair, will I run into errors because I am assigning the same vector to different integer pairs, even though the vector is different each time when I assign the values?

Essentially, if I have:

```
map[Pair1]=Vector1;
Vector1.push_back(1);
Map[Pair2]=Vector1;
```

Will Pair1 and Pair2 be assigned the same vector of values?

Comment: Do you store a reference to the same object / pointer or do you store a copy ?

Comment: I assigned the values essentially just as I did in the example. I don't believe that I stored a pointer but I am fairly ignorant of pointers and have never made an attempt to use them.

Comment: If you store **values**, then you are calling the **copy-constructor** and you have 2 different vector (containing the same values) associated with 2 different key. You can modify one without impacting the other. If you store reference (or pointer), you will associate key with reference to the **same** object. which means that you must be a bit more careful when you access it.

Comment: Basically if you don't use references or pointers each `std::vector` will be copied on assignment and you'll have two different copies. Each time you do `Map[PairX] = Vector` you will copy `Vector` to the map at time of assignment. Each modification will be done on a different object.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: looks to me like your underlying problem is in finding a good model for your problem. can you give some insight what problem you actually want to solve?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the map itself.

If it is a map of `std::vector` *values* or *objects* (as in `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>>`) then each vector in the map will be distinct and unique. Each key will have its own vector object.

With your example, `map[Pair1]` will be a different vector from `map[Pair2]`. *No* modifications to `Vector1` will propagate to `map[Pair1]` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Will Pair1 and Pair2 be assigned the same vector of values?

No.

Firstly, keep in mind that STL container value types need to be assignable so you can not use references as value in the map because they are not assignable. On the another hand, you can use pointers but this will result to be same value for all of the keys in the map if you implement the code like you mentioned.

So, as long as you use assignable types (something like following), you will be good.

```
std::map<pair<int,int> , vector<int> > myMap;
vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);

myMap[std::make_pair(1,1)] = vec;

for(int i=0; i< myMap[make_pair(1,1)].size(); ++i)
    cout << myMap[make_pair(1,1)][i] << " - " ;

cout << endl;
vec.clear();
vec.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(5);

myMap[make_pair(2,1)] = vec;

for(int i=0; i< myMap[make_pair(2,1)].size(); ++i)
    cout << myMap[make_pair(2,1)][i] << " - " ;
```